# Anisotropic lines identification algorithm

Tags: fluid-dynamics, multigrid, unstructured-mesh

I am implementing an algorithm to identify the anisotropic lines in an unstructured mesh. This is done in the framework of an Agglomeration algorithm for Non-Structured multigrid applied to FV discretization of N-S equations.

An **Anisotropic line** can be defined as a line of cells with the same characteristic: to have an aspect ratio that in case of a 2D mesh is more than 4 ($AR>4$) and in 3D more than 8 ($AR>8$). The lines are generated by connecting together the cells along the face of maximum area (or length in 2D). This is quite useful in the geometric multigrid algorithm to preserve the Boundary Layer characteristic structure (made of prism in 2D or of wedge/Hexa in the most classical non-structured meshes). Here after an example from the [paper by Mavriplis](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19980041394/downloads/19980041394.pdf) on the subject.

[image]

In the literature I did not find many algoithms to accomplish the task. Right now I managed to implement the algorithm in [this paper](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19980041394/downloads/19980041394.pdf) by Mavriplis (a reference for the community) that is a sort of greedy-front advancing algorithm. I report here the explanation of line identification algorithm given in the article:

> The line construction
> algorithm begins by pre-computing
> the ratio of maximum
> to average
> adjacent
> edge
> weight for each vertex.The vertices are then sorted according
> to this ratio.The first vertex in this ordered
> list is then picked as the starting point for a line. The line is built by addingto the original vertex the
> neighboring
> vertex which is most strongly connected
> to the current vertex,provided this vertex does not
> already belong to a line,and provided
> the ratio of maximum to minimum edge weights for the current vertex
> is greater than 4 ...
> The line terminates
> when no additional vertex can be found. If
> the originating
> vertex is not a boundary point,then the procedure
> must be repeated
> beginning
> at the original
> vertex,and proceeding
> with the second
> strongest
> connection
> to this point.

The algorithm (even if it has been optimized) ends up to be pretty complex (in terms of branching) and does not guarantee in 3D efficient results, even if it is a good compromise among the final result quality (measured in the preservation of the Boundary layer of the NS mesh) and computational efficiency.

I wanted to ask if there are more efficient algorithms in literature (even from other communities, e.g computer vision community or graph community) that are more efficient and able to work globally (avoiding the front advancing local feature).

Comment: Could you extend your Question as to what an "anisotropic line" is within a mesh?

Comment: Please don't upload images of text; they are not searchable nor accessible.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni fixed

Comment: @MPIchael I have tried to complete

Comment: Mavriplis is usually pretty good bet for the most advanced multigrid stuff, you could try some of the VKI lectures and other materials he wrote after that report, and maybe he has a better algorithm now. The thing is that we know based off the type of problems that we tackle that an advancing front approach is suitable